# running python in atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

i'm trying to run python in the atom editor but every time I try to run my code I  get this:

```
[Command: python -u C:\Users\destinee\Documents\pythonProjects\Testing.py]
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.056s]
```

here is the code I put in:

```
# this is a test
name = Destinee
print("hi")
print(name)
```

**I don't kwon if I need to say this or not but I was using the scprit package for runing the code.

Comment: check if you have your interpreter configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

The Python interpreter is not on your PATH. Either add it, or use an absolute path to the Python executable in Atom's configuration.

If you can set up a venv, you could try launching Atom from inside the venv.